# Possible security flaw php and SQL

Tags: php, sql

So I have this code which basicaly retrieves data from a mysql database:

```
$categoria = $_GET['categoria'];
if($categoria ==""){}else{
$consulta = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productos where categoria='$categoria' ORDER BY     nombre ASC");
while($seleccion = @mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
$nombre = $seleccion['nombre'];
$referencia = $seleccion['referencia'];
$descripcion = $seleccion['descripcion']; 
$imagen = $seleccion['imagen'];
```

And well after that I echo all of the variables... I was wondering, might there be any problem regarding security with a code like this? Is there any risk of it being hacked?
Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you can use `if($categoria !=""){` or `if($categoria){` instead of `if($categoria ==""){}else{`.

Comment: you can't ask two questions in one place. when one question is answered if you have another question ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your existing setup of `mysql` extension the best approach to follow is at least passing the strings through `mysql_real_escape_string`. If you can move to `mysqli` or `pdo` based setup that would be ideal.

```
$consulta = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productos where categoria='" . mysql_real_escape_string($categoria) . "' ORDER BY     nombre ASC");
```

Also a side note from [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1640606/simon-eq) its best you don't prefix the statement with `@`. This adds a bit of overhead to the execution. You should handle errors with `error_reporting` and `display_errors`.

Comment: Don't forget to remove / mention suppressing errors with `@` symbol is a bad idea.

Comment: if i move to mysqli, would I have to make any modifications to the code?

Comment: yes you would need some modifications. all the `_query` functions need to be added the connection parameter. but that just the basic migration to use the mysqli extensions benefits such as prepared statements you will have to overhaul the code. @DanielAntónGarcía

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering, might there be any problem regarding security with a code like this? Is there any risk of it being hacked?

**Yes, it does!** Not only are `mysql_` functions deprecated and no longer being maintained, partly due to the security risk they allow by the use of SQLInjection, they also lack also object oriented capabilities.

The best secure way of connecting and handling database queries that exists now is, either via the `mysqli` or `PDO` interfaces. you should learn either one that suits.

Last but not least, suppressing errors using the `@` method, is pretty much telling your script, not to show you errors, when they occure. Remember, errors should be dealt-with not ignored

Answer (score 1):

This code definitely has serious security flaws. You should use Prepared statement instead. The GET parameter can be modified. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.